# Invoke-Command parameter set cannot be resolved - command works fine outside of script

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I'm archiving files from a network share using PowerShell & `robocopy`. The folders may or may not exist but if they do exist I want to move them to another location. I'm trying to run a series of `robocopy` commands which are predefined in a CSV file. This file also contains a path which I'd like to run a check (`Test-Path`) on to weed out the folders that don't exist. Then I can deal with those at a later date.

Some parts of it seem to work well but the invoke-command is giving me an error:

```
Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
```

When I've googled this error I must admit I don't understand the answers given as they don't relate to my scenario. The invoke command line worked fine when it was not in the if statement it's in now.

This is my code:

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\paths.csv 
foreach ($folder in $csv) {
    $path = $folder.LMCLF #full path to be checked 
    $command = $folder.robo #this is the column name in the CSV which contains the robocopy command
    if (Test-path -Path "$path" -pathtype container) { #check whether path exists
        Invoke-command $folder.robo #run the robocopy command from the CSV
    } else {
        echo $path  " Does not exist!"
    }

    if($LASTEXITCODE) { #check for a robocopy exit code & set relevant message 
        If (($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)) {
            $RoboCopyMessage = "EXITCODE: 0, Succeeded"               
        } elseif (($LASTEXITCODE -gt 0) -and ($LASTEXITCODE -lt 16)) {
            $RoboCopyMessage = "EXITCODE: 1-15, Warning"
        } elseif ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 16) {
            $RoboCopyMessage = "EXITCODE: 16, Error"
        }
    } else {
        $RoboCopyMessage = "Robocopy did not work :("
    }

    Write-Host $RoboCopyMessage " at location: " $folder.LMCLF #some output to the console detailing the robocopy message
    $folder.LMCLF + " |==========| ",  $robocopyMessage | out-file c:\fail.txt -Append      #put the folder & robocopy code into a text file                                            
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$folder.robo`?

Comment: The value would be something like: 

Robocopy.exe "W:\Folder 1\Folder 2" "Q:\Folder 1\Folder 2" /V /S /E /NP /MOVE /R:3 /W:5 /LOG+:C:\RobocopyBatch6.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is that your passing a string to the parameter `-ScriptBlock` in the cmdlet `Invoke-Command`, when it is expecting a Script block.

```
Invoke-Command [-ScriptBlock] <ScriptBlock> [-ArgumentList <Object[]>] 
               [-InputObject <PSObject>] [-NoNewScope] [<CommonParameters>]
```

You could try converting it into a script block before running the command:

```
Invoke-Command ([scriptblock]::Create($folder.robo))
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked. I'm not sure I understand why though!

Answer (score 1):

If your command is a string use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849893.aspx) instead of `Invoke-Command`.